# What operations can make floats leave a [0, 1] range?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I frequently work with `float` or `double` types which are in a range of [0, 1]. I am aware that floating point operations are imprecise, so I typically clamp my values so that they are guaranteed to be in this range before/after operations.

In some cases I rely on floats being not even slightly negative and being exactly `<= 1`, making this necessary.

For example is it necessary in any of these functions:

```cpp
// x and y are guaranteed to be in [0, 1]
float avg(float x, float y) {
    // the average of [0, 1] values should always be in [0, 1]
    return std::clamp<float>((x + y) / 2, 0, 1);
}

float mul(float x, float y) {
    // the product of [0, 1] values should always be in [0, 1]
    return std::clamp<float>(x * y, 0, 1);
}

float pow(float x, unsigned y) {
    // raising an [0, 1] value to any unsigned power should also result in an [0, 1] value
    return std::clamp<float>(std::pow(x, y), 0, 1);
}
```

**Are there any consistent rules for when arithmetic operations can make floats leave the [0, 1] range?**

Comment: i suppose you know that in exact arithmetics none of your above needs the clamp, so the question is whether inaccuracies change anything about that?

Comment: floor, ceil, round, abs, sign and * are probably the only arithmetic operations that stay inside the range. For everything else you have to reason that the combinaton of operations only has results in [0, 1], like in your `avg` function. The + certainly leaves the range but the / brings it back.

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes, that's the point. If floats were real numbers in the mathematical sense, none of this would be necessary. But floats aren't real numbers and maybe there are situations when computing averages or other things break this [0, 1] requirement.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: `sqrt` and, I think, `cbrt` make it into the special function list too, under IEEE754.

Comment: Re: "floating point operations are imprecise" -- they're not. The problem is that floating-point numbers are not real numbers, and many of your instincts based on years of experience aren't applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restricting this answer to IEEE754 if I may.

`0`, `1`, and `2` can all be represented exactly as a `float`. The arithmetic operators are required to return the best floating point value possible. Since `x` and `y` are neither greater than 1, their sum cannot be greater than 2 since then otherwise there would exist a better `float` for the sum. Put another way, the sum of two `float`s a little less than `1` cannot be greater than `2`.

The same applies to the product.

The third one requires a clamp since there are no guarantees that `std::pow(x, y)` returns the best possible `float`.

Comment: For `(a + b + c)` the best value might be > 1 and then `(a + b +c) / 3` could be > 1 too I think. So I think you have to reason it for every function and there aren't any broard rules.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: You do indeed need to consider every function. (a + b + c) / 3 is a different beast.

Comment: @idclev463035818: Sorry, that addition was late to the answer.

Comment: And I think a further edit is needed, both clamps and `2` can be represented exactly.

Comment: Much better answere now. Reasoning about what values can be represented exactly will cover most functions with results in [0, 1]. There might be more functions where the result will be in [0,1 ] but then you have to use more complex reasoning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (a+b+c+...) cannot be >N for N numbers <=1.  I don't have a clean proof.  And it may require N < 2^24.

Comment: Shouldn't pow implementation be weakly monotonic ? Since x^n will be trivially 1 for x=1, we should then have x^n<=1 for x<1. Same for the other bound x=0... n=0 edge case apart.

Comment: @aka.nice - Algebraically speaking it ought to be trivial but bear in mind that an old fashioned although valid implementation of pow(x, y) is exp(y log x). So your inequality argument doesn’t necessarily hold.

Comment: @Bathsheba if log and exp are weakly monotonic, this old fashioned implementation of pow should be too, isn't it? For x=1, log is trivially 0, and I would be amazed that for x<1 some implementation would answer a non negative log. exp(0) is trivially 1, and I would be amazed that exp(x) > 1 for x<0... same around 0, exp() won't be negative...

Answer (score 1):

**Corner issue**

```
float pow(float x, unsigned y) {
    // raising an [0, 1] value to any unsigned power should also result in an [0, 1] value
    return std::clamp<float>(std::pow(x, y), 0, 1);
}
```

With `std::pow(±0, 0)` may lead to outside [0..1] range (or cause a domain error) as that result is not specified by `std::pow()` nor mathematically resolved: [Zero to the power of zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero).

If following [IEEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero#IEEE_floating-point_standard), the result is 1 yet a compliant library is not required to follow that.

If not following IEEE, and `std::pow(0,0)` returns NAN, I'd expect `std::clamp(NAN,0,1)` to also return NAN and break the system.

Candidate alternative code

```
return (y==0) ? 1 : x;
```

---

Note a result of the functions could be -0.0, yet that value is still in the [0...1] range.

I see no concerns with `mul()`, `avg()` regarding -0.0, intermediate calculation done at higher precision and variant rounding modes.